# MySql Posting 2 tables

Tags: mysql, database, post

I am trying to learn mySql DB, I have 2 tables that I am working with, one for the users and one for the cats that the registered users post.

```
USERS:
+----+---------+------------------+----------+--------+
| id | name    | email            | password | cats   |
+----+---------+------------------+----------+--------+
|  3 | omar    | omar@hotmail.com | omar     | []     |
| 14 | dana    | dana@gmail.com   | anad     | []     |
|  7 | mama    | mami@gmail.com   | mama     | []     |
|  9 | tata    | tata@gmail.com   | tata     | []     |
+----+---------+------------------+----------+--------+  

CATS:
+----+---------+----------------+---------+
| id | name    | age    | breed | ownerId |
+----+---------+--------+-------+---------+
|  5 | mimi    |      2 | Grey  |      14 |
| 10 | Negri   |     19 | black |       3 |
+----+---------+----------------+---------+
```

What i want to do is, whenever a cat is posted in the CATS DB I want for that catId to appear in the USERS DB in the owner'sId cats array.
For example the cat Mimi has ID = 5 and the ownerID = 14. If you look in the users table, ID 14 corresponds to user Dana. I want the cats Id(5) to appear in Dana's cats array.
This is the code I have by now : the functions that posts a new cat in the CATS DB.

```
function addCat (catsData, connection){
    let {name, age, breed, ownerId} = catsData;
    const mySqlQuery = `insert into cats(name, age, breed, ownerId) values ('${name}', '${age}', '${breed}', '${ownerId}')`;
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(mySqlQuery, 
            function (error, results, fields) {
                if(error){
                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    resolve(results);
                }
            })
    })
};


async function postCatsHandler(req, res, next) {
try {
    let data = req.body;
    const connection = req.app.get("mySqlConnection");
    const addedCatId =  await addCat(data, connection);
      console.log("addedCatId::", addedCatId);
            req.result ='{...data, id : addedCatId}' 
        next();
    }
    catch(error){
        next(error);
    }
};

Any tips or information is greatly valued.

Many thanks.
```

Comment: You should not  store value in an array  .. you should normalize your db and use a proper  table for mantain the relation between cats and users

Comment: There is no `array` datatype in MYSQL (unless you are refering to JSON?).

Comment: @GMB yes that's what i'm referring to...?

Comment: You should not store cats array in `USERS` table. Any time when you need this array you can query it: `SELECT USERS.*, GROUP_CONCAT(CATS.id) AS CATS FROM USERS LEFT JOIN CATS ON CATS.ownerId = USERS.id GROUP BY USERS.id`